# Momentjs seconds from now

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var startdate  =  '02.05.2018 18:05:03';
```

How to find out how many minutes have passed from startdate to now?

My try

```
var exp = moment(startdate);
minutes = moment().diff(exp, 'minutes');
```

but result 124764 it not right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing of date strings are not consistent among browsers. Always pass the format of the string if it is in non-ISO format to prevent unwanted bugs:

```
var exp = moment(startdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
moment().diff(exp, 'minutes');
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference between two moment time objects, you can use `.diff()`. Then you can use any of `asHours()`, `asMinutes()`, `asSeconds()` to get human-readable time difference.

```
var start  =  moment('02.05.2018 18:05:03');
var end  =  moment('02.05.2018 18:11:03');

var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
var mins = duration.asMinutes();

console.log(mins)
```

In your case, you can simply call `moment().diff(time)` since you want to get difference between the time you specify and now.

```
var time  =  moment('02.05.2018 18:05:03');

var duration = moment.duration(moment().diff(time));
var mins = duration.asMinutes();

console.log(mins)
```